# Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis How can I configure the library having the eval command disabled

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using the [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/fc94cb7bcee8d37378ecc471a53b72cb4fb1782c/src/Caching/StackExchangeRedis/src) which works with
[StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) library underneath to handle all the Redis related work. Currently I have a user that does not have the eval command enabled. How can I configure the library to not use the eval command and try the SET command directly?

This is the exception that I am getting

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: NOPERM this user has no permissions to run the 'eval' command or its subcommand
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache.SetAsync(String key, Byte[] value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options, CancellationToken token)
```

I know that this is related with the setup of the user, but as we are not going to have that right enabled, how can we work using the library?

I am using dotnet core 6 and targeting StackExchange.Redis version 2.2.88

I open a discution in github: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/2315 but this may not be related directly with StackExchange.Redis, It is that [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/fc94cb7bcee8d37378ecc471a53b72cb4fb1782c/src/Caching/StackExchangeRedis/src) is working with eval by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I configure the library to not use the eval command and try the SET command directly?

You can't.

That behavior is [buried deep into the RedisCache type](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/fc94cb7bcee8d37378ecc471a53b72cb4fb1782c/src/Caching/StackExchangeRedis/src/RedisCache.cs#L184) ([here is the script](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/fc94cb7bcee8d37378ecc471a53b72cb4fb1782c/src/Caching/StackExchangeRedis/src/RedisCache.cs#L36)), which is exposed by the Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis Nuget package. You simply can't change it but you may just avoid using this package and invoke commands on Redis directly.

Finally, just to clarify, as your question seems to mean the opposite: SE.Redis is a Redis client library and, like most libraries of this kind, does not interpret LUA scripts (it parses them with the goal of extracting keys and values - but this is a whole different concept) and simply can't transform a given script into a sequence of Redis commands. Moreover, LUA scripts can be much more than just a simple sequence of Redis commands.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I was trying to use the native libraries but in this case I will have to search for an alternative. Mainly something that implements the **IDistributedCache** interface.